# Set jQuery conditions when HTML upload field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've got an HTML form with an upload.

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file">
```

Using jQuery I am doing a client side size check of the file.

```
jQuery('#uploaded_file').bind('change', function() {
var size = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;

if (size > 3.00){
jQuery("#upload_msg").html('File size is ' + size.toFixed(2) + ' / 3.00 MB.');
}

if (size <= 3.00){
jQuery("#upload_msg").html('File size is ' + size.toFixed(2) + ' / 3.00 MB.');
}});
```

I want to set a condition so that if a user chooses a file, then changes their mind and unchooses a file to upload that the jQuery adjust back to it's original form.

How do I set a condition for that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check value with val() method of input tag and if it contains filename you should go with your logic otherwise skip your logic.

Comment: I will see what I can do. I'm pretty new to jQuery because I avoided it as long as possible.